# List() in class

Tags: php, arrays, class

My script don't wanna work, if it doesn't have list():

```
list($contact->contact) = $contact->contactArray();
```

I wanna insert list() into the class, cause I don't want use this ever I must use my array, but when i write this code into the class, I get information:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LIST, expecting T_VARIABLE

My part of class:

```
  public $contact;
  list($contact) = $this->contactArray();

  public function contactArray()
  {

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `contact_id`, `contact_name`, `contact_surname`, `group_id`, `contact_telephone`, `contact_email` FROM `contact` ORDER BY `contact_surname` ASC") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $contact[$row["contact_id"]] = array(
        "name" => $row["contact_name"],
        "surname" => $row["contact_surname"],
        "group_id" => $row["group_id"],
        "telephone" => $row["contact_telephone"],
        "email" => $row["contact_email"]
      );
    }

    return array($contact);

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only constants, variables and methods are allowed inside a class declaration. You could put this code inside the constructor though:

```
  // ...

  public $contact;

  public function __construct()
  {
      list($this->contact) = $this->contactArray();
  }
```